# no matching constructor for initialization of 'AEffGUIEditor' with VSTGUI

Tags: c++, macos, vst

I've made a plugin using the VST SDK 2.4. Up until now I've been using the generic interface to control the plugin but now I'm trying to add a custom interface using the VSTGUI library.

I've set up editor files and tried to use the code as outlined in the example code packaged with the library. I'm a bit worried that there might not be total compatibility with OSX Yosemite, however at this stage I'm fighting some rudimentary problems.

I want to know if i'm doing something wrong, or should I give up using VSTGUI with OSX 10.10?

On compilation, I get the following error:
    ./TutorialEditor.h:42:32: error:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'AEffGUIEditor'
    Editor (const void* ptr) : AEffGUIEditor (ptr) {}
                               ^              ~~~
vstsdk2.4/vstgui.sf/vstgui/aeffguieditor.h:51:7: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type
      'const void *' to 'const AEffGUIEditor'
class AEffGUIEditor : public AEffEditor
      ^
vstsdk2.4/vstgui.sf/vstgui/aeffguieditor.h:55:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot
      convert argument of incomplete type 'const void *' to 'AudioEffect *'
        AEffGUIEditor (AudioEffect* effect);
    ^
```

The initialisation in the constructor of my vst plugin looks like this:

```
extern AEffGUIEditor* createEditor (AudioEffectX*);
setEditor (createEditor (this));
```

Here's the TutorialEditor.cpp code:

```
#include "TutorialEditor.h"

AEffGUIEditor* createEditor (AudioEffectX* effect) {
    return new Editor (effect);
}

bool Editor::open (void* ptr) {
    CRect frameSize (0, 0, 300, 300);
    frame = new CFrame (frameSize, ptr, this);
    return true;
}
void Editor::close () {
    delete frame;
    frame = 0;
}
```

Here's the TutorialEditor.h code:

```
#include "vstgui.sf/vstgui/aeffguieditor.h"

class Editor : public AEffGUIEditor {
public:
    Editor (void* ptr) : AEffGUIEditor (ptr) {}
    bool open (void* ptr);
    void close ();
};
```

Comment: If you get a compiler error you're obviously doing something wrong. Pass the correct argument type to the base class constructor and you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler not cast that `void*` to a `AudioEffect*` automatically.

You can cast it manually by writing

```
Editor (void* ptr) : AEffGUIEditor ((AudioEffect*)ptr) {}
```

but ideally you should avoid using void* at all in this case.

Try to replace

```
Editor (void* ptr) : AEffGUIEditor (ptr) {}
```

by

```
Editor (AudioEffect* ptr) : AEffGUIEditor (ptr) {}
```

if possible.

The less type information you lose, the better.